# Android - Upload a File(*/*) with URI Path

Tags: android, file, upload, uri

I'm not good at English, so I'm so sorry. I have a problem and I did research but I couldn't find solution.

I want to upload any file(users can select pdf, doc, txt, jpg...) to server with PHP. Now, I can choose a file from android device. But I can't get absolute path for choosed file. I have just URİ path like below:

```
1. uri.toString():

content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/7
```

or

```
2. uri.getPath()

/content/7
```

Now, I'm trying upload a file to server with uri path. Can I do this?

My API version : 23

Comment: There is no conversion from a URI to a real path. Just read the data from the URI.

Comment: Given limitations on the way that `Uri` values work, IMHO your best option is to use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content. Use that to make a local copy of the content (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`). Upload to your server from that local copy (e.g., [using OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#posting-a-file)). Then, delete the cached copy.

Comment: Great! I understood this, really nice opinion but I did some research and I didn't find anything, all examples about images but my app don't only images.